Remove javascript in response ajax
Now i got this issue actually i don't know why, this is the first time that i faced this issue.
let me explain it to you.

i code php wordpress.
i have ajax request.
the response of this ajax request will be shown object. but my response include javascript

here is the ajax.php file:
<?php
function test_ajax()
{
    $data = [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => ' has been load successfully.',
    ];
    wp_send_json_success($data);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_test_ajax', 'test_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_ajax', 'test_ajax');
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var indexingMessage = $("#indexing-message");
        $("#index-urls").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
            console.log("Loading...");
            indexingMessage.text("Loading...");
            var urls = $("#urls").val().trim().split(/\r?\n/); // Split URLs by newlines
            if (!urls.length) {
                indexingMessage.text("Please enter URLs.");
                return;
            }
            function indexUrl(url) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        action: "test_ajax",
                        url: url,
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: (response_ajax) => {
                        console.log("Response AJAX:", response_ajax);
                        if (response_ajax.success) {
                            indexingMessage.text("Success:: " + url);
                        } else {
                            indexingMessage.text("Error! An error occurred. Please try again later. Please check your browser's log for details");
                        }
                    },
                    error: (xhr, status, error) => {
                        console.log("Error AJAX:", JSON.stringify(error));
                        indexingMessage.text("Error! An error occurred. Please try again later. Please check your browser's log for details.");
                    }
                });

            }
            for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                indexUrl(urls[i]);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

here is the load-urls.php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Load URLs
Plugin URI: 
Description: Custom author template for WordPress.
Version: 1.0
Author URI:
License: GPL2
*/
include_once ('ajax.php');
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_settings_page');

function my_plugin_settings_page()
{
    add_menu_page(
        'My Plugin Settings',
        'My Plugin',
        'manage_options',
        'my-plugin-settings',
        'my_plugin_settings_content',
        'dashicons-admin-settings' // Optional icon
    );
}

function my_plugin_settings_content()
{
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>My Plugin Settings</h1>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('my-plugin-settings-group'); ?>
            <div id="my-plugin-settings-section">
                <h3>key</h3>
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th scope="row"><label for="key"> Key</label></th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea style="height:200px;width:100%" type="text" name="key" id="key"
                                 size="60" ><?php echo esc_attr(get_option('key')); ?></textarea>
                            <p class="description">Enter your key here.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
            <?php submit_button('Save Changes'); ?>
        </form>
        <h3> URLs</h3>
        <table>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="urls">URLs  (separate URLs with newlines)</label></th>
                <td>
                    <textarea style="height:200px;width:100%" name="urls" id="urls" rows="5"
                        cols="50"></textarea>
                    <p class="description">Enter each URL on a separate line.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>Click the button below to load the URLs you entered above.</p>
        <button id="index-urls" class="button button-primary">Load URLs</button>
        <p id="indexing-message"></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_register_settings');

function my_plugin_register_settings()
{
    register_setting('my-plugin-settings-group', 'key', 'sanitize_text_field');
}
?>

This is the returned result:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var indexingMessage = $("#indexing-message");
        $("#index-urls").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
            console.log("Loading...");
            indexingMessage.text("Loading...");
            var urls = $("#urls").val().trim().split(/\r?\n/); // Split URLs by newlines
            if (!urls.length) {
                indexingMessage.text("Please enter URLs.");
                return;
            }
            function indexUrl(url) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://192.168.146.1/kiguiadsence/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        action: "test_ajax",
                        url: url,
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: (response_ajax) => {
                        console.log("Response AJAX:", response_ajax);
                        if (response_ajax.success) {
                            indexingMessage.text("Success:: " + url);
                        } else {
                            indexingMessage.text("Error! An error occurred. Please try again later. Please check your browser's log for details");
                        }
                    },
                    error: (xhr, status, error) => {
                        console.log("Error AJAX:", JSON.stringify(error));
                        indexingMessage.text("Error! An error occurred. Please try again later. Please check your browser's log for details.");
                    }
                });

            }
            for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                indexUrl(urls[i]);
            }
        });
    }); </script>{"success":true,"data":{"success":true,"message":" has been load successfully."}}

hope everyone can help me.
I just want the return result to be
{"success":true,"data":{"message":" has been load successfully."}}


"this is my code:" - located where, exactly?

with this set of shared code we can't get issue. Please add more detail to it; like in which file which code is written and how you are accessing it.

Are you sure this problem is related to Wordpress itself? Are you struggling with the JS part or the PHP part?

You have missed opening & closing script tag. Your $(document).ready(function () { must be in script tag.  If your getting this response in php then use regex.

I am coding a plugin in wordpress and using ajax.
this is the index file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jqZuIkXLWvAlVKVgX1X19Y3utw4i0kUf/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h-6pWCJOdv0rL4zgCX93EVpSHSDKCx2K/view

Please add all clarification (including all relevant source code) to your question by editing it, not to the comment section and not as links to any external ressource

Hi @NicoHaase, i was updated info detail

I suggest that you move the JavaScript code from ajax.php to a separate file. Then use WordPress's wp_enqueue_script() function to properly enqueue this JavaScript file. eg.
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'ajax-script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

    // Pass AJAX URL to JavaScript
    wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');

Your test_ajax() function in ajax.php should remain unchanged.

tks.  I added it but my response is still not json.

How do you return the response from the ajax call? Can you paste something here? You should ensure it is returning as illustrated above using json_encode. Then you will receive your response in an object format.

Currently, I am using the following code to return data:
function test_ajax() { $data = [ 'success' => true, 'message' => ' has been load successfully.', ]; wp_send_json_success($data); } add_action('wp_ajax_test_ajax', 'test_ajax'); add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_ajax', 'test_ajax');

I updated detail in the question

Try this:
function test_ajax() { $data = [ 'success' => true, 'message' => ' has been load successfully.', ]; wp_send_json_success(json_encode($data)); } add_action('wp_ajax_test_ajax', 'test_ajax'); add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_ajax', 'test_ajax');

tks @FrankDexDevs, but it not work.
it still include javascript on response.

I suggest that you move the JavaScript code from ajax.php to a separate file. Then use WordPress's wp_enqueue_script() function to properly enqueue this JavaScript file. eg.
`function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', plugin_dir_url(FILE) . 'ajax-script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
// Pass AJAX URL to JavaScript
wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');`
Your test_ajax() function in ajax.php should remain unchanged.

tks @FrankDexDevs. I have solved the problem by your solution.
but I cannot know the reason why

Nice. Your PHP file (ajax.php) will only execute within the WordPress environment, and the JavaScript code will be properly included and executed without generating unwanted output. You could mark this as the answer to help anyone else struggling with these issues. I edited it too... Cheers and happy coding
